# Use variants in TYPO3 v9 to translate validationErrorMessages in a form

Tags: typo3, variant, typo3-9.x

I want to translate the validationErrorMessage of an finisher with the new variant. Below is a piece of my code showing properties of the field labeled with Vorname.

```
renderables:
  - defaultValue: ''
    type: Text
    identifier: text-1
    label: Vorname

    properties:
      fluidAdditionalAttributes:
        required: required
        minlength: '5'
        maxlength: '100'
      validationErrorMessages:
        - code: '1238110957'
          message: 'Die maximale....'
        - code: '1221551320'
          message: 'Es sind nur alphanumerische Zeichen erlaubt'
        - code: '1221560910'
          message: 'Bitte geben Sie Ihren Vornamen an'
      elementDescription: 'Ihr Vorname'
```

To translate this, I use the following code. While the translation for label and elementDescription works fine, the one for the validationErrorMessage don't.

```
    variants:
      - identifier: language-variant-en
        condition: 'siteLanguage("locale") == "en_US.UTF-8"'
        label: Firstname
        properties:
          validationErrorMessages:
            message: 'Englisch Die maximale...'
          elementDescription: Your first name
```

I think, the problem is to adress each of the message properties the right way but I havn't found a solution, yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the solution in itself is quite simple. Simply take over the passage to be translated (validationErrorMessages) completely as you can see.

Pay attention to the hyphen and the indent:

```
variants:
      - identifier: language-variant-en
        condition: 'siteLanguage("locale") == "en_US.UTF-8"'
        label: Firstname
        properties:
          validationErrorMessages:
            - code: '1238110957'
              message: 'The maximum length is 100 characters, the minimum length 5 characters'
            - code: '1221551320'
              message: 'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed'
            - code: '1221560910'
              message: 'Please enter your first name'
          elementDescription: Your first name
```